# Print size/length of string in clipboard on windows

Tags: windows-7, clipboard

I'm hoping there exists a quick hack that will tell me the length of a string contained in the windows clipboard.  (if it is in fact a string).

It's not for any kind of production code, and I'm not tied to any particular language.

TIA

Comment: You can also do it [in vb / vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552299/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-using-access-vba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.OpenClipboard(None)
print len(ctypes.c_char_p(ctypes.windll.user32.GetClipboardData(1)).value)
ctypes.windll.user32.CloseClipboard()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

```
java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
String content = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
int size = content.length();
```

Add additional error checking as required.