# Copy text using VBA in Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I try to copy the `strContents` into clipboard but I can't.
My code is:

```
Dim value_currency As Variant
Dim strContents As String

value_currency = value_currency_txt.value
strContents = NumberToString(value_currency) & " (" & Format(value_currency_txt.Value, "Currency") & ")"

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
```

`NumberToString` converts number to string.

When I use `MsgBox strContents` gives me the desired result but when I try to copy the `strContents` it gives me an error 2406 - the command copy isn't available now.

How can I copy the text into clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following is going to work, then this question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5552423/8418):

```
Dim value_currency As Variant
Dim strContents As String

strContents = NumberToString(value_currency) & " (" & Format(value_currency_txt.Value, "Currency") & ")"

Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
clipboard.SetText strContents
clipboard.PutInClipboard
```

Comment: It gives me the error User-defined type not defined. I think something is wrong with the `MSForms.Dataobjects`

Comment: I had to add FM20.dll from windows system32 as reference

Answer (score 1):

If you have a form at hand, you can use this simple method:

You can easily send a command that copies the currently selected text in a textbox of the form to the clipboard:

```
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
```

Create a button and a (tiny) textbox on the main form: *btnClip* and *txtClip*.

Assign this code to the button:

```
 Private Sub btnClip_Click()
     Dim strClip As String

     ' Empty textbox to copy from.
     Me.txtClip.Value = Null
     ' Retrieve your data.
     strClip = "Some text to copy for later pasting."
     If Len(strClip) > 0 Then
         ' Insert the text in the textbox where it can be copied.
         Me.txtClip.Value = strClip
         ' Move focus to the textbox which will select all text.
         Me.txtClip.SetFocus
         ' Copy the selected text to the clipboard.
         DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
         ' Return focus to the button.
         Me.btnClip.SetFocus
     End If
 End Sub
```

The trick is the small textbox, txtClip. It can be placed anywhere and doesn't even need to have a size; it can be zero x zero.