# Pasting Values from Clipboard into the first empty row of open Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard, paste

I have a dataframe from R that I need to paste into the first empty row of an open Excel spreadsheet.

I have tried numerous things.

This code throws a "Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error".

```
Dim NextRow As Range
Set NextRow = Range("B" & Sheets("TC-9").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
Worksheets("TC-9").Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I also tried using xlUp to look from the bottom up to find the first empty row.

```
Cells(Range("C1000000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552299/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-using-access-vba

Comment: What is the workflow that you are following: you copy the R code, then you select your open worksheet, right?... Do you have a button on your excel file with a routine or something like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022245/get-text-from-clipboard-using-gettext-avoid-error-on-empty-clipboard can you use the R Addin?

Comment: You are correct.  I built a routine in R that scraps some data off the web then processes its.  At the end it copies the dataframe from R onto the clipboard.  I need it to then paste the data into Excel.

Comment: what's your issue? isn't it pasting anything? or is it pasting from the wrong cell?

Comment: This first code set throws a "Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: R allows you to export dataframes as csv files, files which are easily read by Excel. Why go through the clipboard?

Comment: My boss wants to be able to run the package through a push button on Excel meaning the spreadsheet is already open.  To do R to csv would require closing the spreadsheet (which my boss is not to keen on) then reopening.  Using the clipboard we can skip the closing process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
dim lastrow as integer

With Worksheets("TC-9")
    lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    .Range("A" & lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _ 
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `PasteSpecial` line, you are specifying a `Range` as `Range("A" & NextRow)`.  `NextRow` has been defined as a `Range` itself, and concatenating a `String` with a `Range` isn't valid.

Change your code as follows:

```
Dim NextRow As Long
NextRow = Sheets("TC-9").Range("B" & Sheets("TC-9").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("TC-9").Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial
```

Note:  This will copy a single value from the clipboard.  If you want multiple values copied to a single row, it will work if they are tab-delimited but not if they are comma-delimited.  (It can probably be done, but would require a bit more work.)

---

In your second piece of code you used `Range("C1000000000")` but Excel currently has a limitation of 1,048,576 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding, you're trying to paste a value in that's in the Windows clipboard. The problem is that you can't use Paste Values when pasting from Windows, because it's not copying an Excel object.

Rather than using `Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone`, try just using PasteSpecial on its own:

```
Range.PasteSpecial
```

You could also just use the .Paste method, but you'll need to select your range first:

```
Range("A1").select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

It doesn't matter what method you use to find the `Range`, just how you paste it. I prefer the former method, but both should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Appending into last of document**

```
Set Range2 = ActiveDocument.Content 
 Range2.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 
 Range2.Paste
```

[Reference Link Microsoft-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.paste)