# Copy from clipboard and paste into a userform

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I am using a program that populates a table with data, and the sizes (col/row) of these table grows every period in an unpredicted way.

So let's say I copy the contents of the table into clipboard, and what I want to know is:

**Is it possible to paste this data into some sort of userform instead of going to an Excel sheet and then loading the source into a listbox?**

I couldn't find any source material on this. I was interested to know if it was possible or if not, why it's not a good idea to do this!

I did find a lot of material about using the source of a table to populate a listbox, or, using a right click to copy data from a userform, but not the other way around.

Comment: since you know how to populate a listbox from a source table, why don't you do that right before (and avoid) copying data into clipboard?

Comment: Post some code and we'll try to help if it's not working.  And yes you are right, it is a stupid question for SO.

Comment: Where do you recommend posting this into? @MarkFitzgerald

Comment: I don't think it is possible. If I remember correctly you can assign all items at once `ListBox1.List = Split("a b c")`

Comment: A perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552299/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-using-access-vba (identical for Access and Excel, since it's both VBA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This copyies any info in the current selection in clipboard and puts it into a textbox,

```
Dim clipBoard As MsForms.DataObject
Set clipBoard = New MsForms.DataObject

clipBoard.GetFromClipboard
TextBox1.Value = clipBoard.GetText(1)
```

Of course you can adapt this to have the data put into different form controls.  You will need to handle when the clipboard is empty.